How do I include/define multiple english fonts within babel?
How might I be able to include multiple english fonts within a babel document (that has english as its main language)?  For example, how might I use a different font (or subfont within a font family) for an abstract, description, marginal note, etc?
Here's my document:
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{apacite} 

 

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=1.0in,bmargin=1.0in,lmargin=1.0in,rmargin=1.0in,headheight=0.5in,headsep=0.2in,footskip=0.5in}

\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}  
\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}


\babeltags{
  hebrew=hebrew,
  greek=greek,
  ancientgreek=ancientgreek,
  syriac=syriac,
  german=german,
} 


\babelfont{rm}{Minion Pro Medium}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{SBL Hebrew}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{Accordance}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Minion Pro Display}
\babelfont[syriac]{rm}{Accordance}
\babelfont[german]{rm}{1517 Gilgengart}
\babelfont{tt}{2004 Uncialis Romana}






\usepackage{setspace}









\doublespacing 

\begin{document}




\title{Professional Development Planning Portfolio}
\author{Steve Bauer}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract} test  \end{abstract}


\section{Test}
 
 
\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{”\textsuperscript{1} בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃ \textsuperscript{2} וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃“} (Genesis 1:1-2 HMT-W4)\foreignlanguage{ancientgreek}{Ⲉⲓⲡⲉⲛⲇⲉⲡⲣⲟⲥⲧⲓⲛⲁⲥⲧⲟⲩⲥⲡⲉ} \foreignlanguage{greek}{Εἶπεν δὲ καὶ πρός τινας τοὺς πεποιθότας ἐφ’ ἑαυτοῖς ὅτι εἰσὶν δίκαιοι καὶ ἐξουθενοῦντες τοὺς λοιποὺς τὴν παραβολὴν ταύτην.}  \foreignlanguage{syriac}{ܘܶܐܡܰܪ ܗ݈ܘܳܐ ܡܰܬ݂ܠܳܐ ܗܳܢܳܐ ܠܽܘܩܒ݂ܰܠ ܐ݈ܢܳܫ̈ܳܐ ܐܝܠܶܝܢ ܕ݁ܰܬ݂ܟ݂ܺܝܠܺܝܢ ܥܰܠ ܢܰܦ݂ܫܗܽܘܢ ܕ݁ܺܐܝܬ݂ܰܝܗܽܘܢ ܙܰܕ݁ܺܝܩ̈ܶܐ ܘܒ݂ܳܣܶܝܢ ܥܰܠ ܟ݁ܽܠܢܳܫ} \foreignlanguage{german}{du has mein leben genommmen}  \texttt{ in principio erat verbum}  


do.”\cite{Indivisible}  
















\bibliography{CMHC}  
\bibliographystyle{apacite}






\end{document} 


\babelfont is mainly for automatic language dependent font selection. What you want is an explicit font selection. This can be done the same as without babel (depending on the engine either use fontspec or \fontfamily, \usefont etc.). BTW: rm, sf, and tt families should be enough, i.e. with different series, shapes and weights. You should never mix lots of fonts. Nevertheless you can use,e.g. Epimanes instead of rm to define another font family. See the babel manual for more information.

Ok, so if I use fontspec, it won't conflict with babel, will it?

Just out of curiosity, do you use the Accordance software? I see you use the font. As to your question use fontspec, it does not conflict with babel. Normally one tries to keep the same fontface for various sections but vary the weight, size and shape for different effects.

ok, thanks for the confirmation.  And yes, I've used Accordance for many years now.

I'm confused: your code uses several languages, but not English, yet your question is about English. That is, you've not told Babel English is the main language. So you've not loaded any settings for it.

I'm pretty new at this.  If the proper/preferred way is to set english as the default and have the rest as exceptions, then what would that look like?
